# Dynamic Dashlet in Alfresco Share

Tags: customization, share, alfresco

As a user experience requirement, I need to create a dynamic dashlet.

According to what I need, a dynamic dashlet would be a special dashlet that can load inside "almost every content". I say almost every content because of course this kind of dashlet would have its own limits of course. At the same time, it would be nice that the dynamic dashlet has the ability of being maximized, what in fact would show the real content (for example, an Alfresco page).

Perhaps my question is ambiguous, but the intention to give the user the chance of check execute common functionality inside that special dashlet, this way the user doesn't have to leave the dashboard improving the user experience as a consequence.

Did anybody have had such requirement or similar before? Would that be possible to do?

I would like to know some tips and suggestions in order to find out the right approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try re-using the webview Dashlet which can also show another page.

The only problem is that not every part which is visible in Share can be accessed via url. Sure the template gets build up by regions of *.ftl's but that doesn't mean you can 'just' view the *.ftl.

The only 'dynamic' thing I see is making a custom page template which shows one or couple of regions which are dynamically build by the url.

e.g. pointing to share/page/customPage?region1=documentlibrary should insert the documentlibrary template within that page and thus it can be shown within the iFrame of the webview Dashlet.

Actually the documentlibrary is a bad example, because there is already a portletMode available for Liferay. But hopefully you'll get my point.

Comment: Ummm, the idea of a custom page with several regions sounds good. You mean, a page with a template with 'n' regions (where 'n' is as many as different dynamic contents are required) and load the content of the dashlet by invoking the URL that corresponds as you have explained (share/page/customPage?regionx). Then my dynamic dashlet would have a single iFrame within the ftl file. Did I understand correctly? Another thing would be to find the best and most suitable way to communicate with the dashlet... I've been reading something about dashlets communications. Is it similar to Liferay portlets?

Comment: No it isn't really. Dashlets aren't portlets so there is no real binding. Dashlets does share the same session, hence you can trigger JS events which could change something in another Dashlet. Alfresco uses the same mechanism to refresh content through the "refresh" event in JS YUI. If you check the SDK on event.bubble or bubble.fire you will find samples.

Comment: Oh yes I know dashlets aren´t portlets hehehe I was just asking if there exists an equivalent mechanism that allows you to communicate dashlets as you can do with portlets, that´s all. Anyway I still have to learn a loooot of things about Sharand Surf. Thanks very much Tahir.